# How to receive data from a database using AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I use a comment box in my web page and saved user input comments. Now what I want is to display them using AJAX. I set a javascript timer to get comments one by one. But I don't know how to use AJAX to retrieve data. This is the php file

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("continental_tourism");
$query = "SELECT comment_id from comment";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$counter++;
} 

$comment_number = rand(1,$counter);
$query_comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE comment_id = '$comment_number'");
if (!$query_comment) { 
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}   
while($result_comment = mysql_fetch_array($query_comment)) {

echo $result_comment['comment'];

}
?>
```

following is the script part in the main file.

```
function timeMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout("show_comment()",3000);
}

function show_comment(){

}
```

How should i write the AJAX code to the?

> function show_comment()

If someone can explain the AJAX code line by line, I'll be great full.

Comment: everything you need: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: first try something on your own, there are many examples, just google, also using jQuery would be best

Comment: Do you want to display a single comment per 3 seconds?

Comment: Instead of doing the counting using a while loop, look up the `COUNT` function in SQL. It will be quicker.

Comment: Also you are making an assumption that `comment_id` start at zero and an sequential.

Comment: @nithin no different comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move your all php script to another php file say getdata.php and use your ajax function in your file where you want to show the data say it is index.php. (this is for easy to use code). Now your index.php file should look like

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="comments"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="include/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript>
    function show_comments() {
         $.ajax({
            url:getdata.php
            success:function(data){
               $("#comments").append(data);
            }
         }); 
  </script>
 </html>
```

I am using jquery.ajax function of jquery. This is some hint how you can do this. I hope it will help you to accomplish your task.

Comment: i need to display the comments in a div. which is in the same index.php. How can i do that?

Comment: function timeMsg()
    {
    var t=setTimeout("show_comment()",3000);
    }
    
    function show_comments() {
             $.ajax({
                url:"show_comment.php",
                success:function(data){
                   $("#comments").append(data);
                }
             });

Comment: @Ravindu the code `$("#comments").append(data);` specify the id of the div or any thing where you want to display the comments. #comments is the id of the div where the comments are being displayed

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method using the link to your PHP script as URL. That should call your PHP script and your script should echo the output.

You should consider `json_encode`-ing your output from php script before echoing it.

And I think, instead of doing this -

```
$query = "SELECT comment_id from comment";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$counter++;
}
```

you can query `SELECT COUNT(comment_id) from comment` and get the count.

Comment: But in my .php file ther are some more echo commands i used. So how can i choose the correct one i need, to display comment???

Comment: To use with AJAX, you need to be careful of what you echo. I'll suggest you to put all your data in an array, `json_encode()` it and then echo the encoded that string. in the jquery part, the received `data` should be a json string. You can decode it and use it.

Comment: I created another .php to do the above problem. Now the next problem is how can i displat this in a div.